# Modify month number to month name and print it once for same month rows

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm a beginner in programming with awk, Please, I would like the presentation in this way:

I Have:

```
month D1 D2 D3
01    25 26 23
01    13 12 11
01    48 45 12
02    77 87 45
02    63 99 12
```

I'd like:

```
month D1 D2 D3
January 25 26 23
        13 12 11
        48 45 12
February 77 87 45
         63 99 12
```

Comment: please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` (to get the list of month names in the user's locale) + `awk`, that could be:

```bash
zmodload zsh/langinfo
awk -v months=${(vj[:])langinfo[(I)MON_<1-12>]} '
  BEGIN{split(months, month, ":")}
  NR > 1 {
    this_month = month[0+$1]
    if (this_month == last)
      $1 = blanks
    else
      blanks = sprintf("%*s", length(last = $1 = this_month), "")
  }
  {print}' < your-file
```

Beware that in locales where month names contain characters encoded on more than one byte (like `février` in a `fr_FR.UTF-8` locale where the `é` is encoded on 2 bytes), alignment may be off if using an `awk` implementation such as `mawk` that is not multi-byte aware.

For instance, I get:

```
month D1 D2 D3
janvier 25 26 23
        13 12 11
        48 45 12
février 77 87 45
        63 99 12
```

with `gawk`, but

```
month D1 D2 D3
janvier 25 26 23
        13 12 11
        48 45 12
février 77 87 45
         63 99 12
```

with `mawk`.

If you want the month names in English regardless of the user's locale, you can set `LC_ALL=C`.

Answer (score 2):

File: `months.awk`

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    # Months array initialization
    months["01"] = "January"
    months["02"] = "February"
    months["03"] = "March"
    months["04"] = "April"
    months["05"] = "May"
    months["06"] = "June"
    months["07"] = "July"
    months["08"] = "August"
    months["09"] = "September"
    months["10"] = "October"
    months["11"] = "November"
    months["12"] = "December"
}
{
    # key is the month number
    k = $1
}
! (k in months) {
    # Month not found: print line as is
    print
    # Next line!
    next
}
! (k in tabs) {
    # month name read from array
    month_name = months[k]
    # month name length
    month_len = length(month_name)
    # remove month number into the line
    gsub(/^[0-9]+ +/, "")
    # print new line
    printf("%*.*s %s\n", month_len, month_len, month_name, $0)
    # store in tabs array the month length
    tabs[k] = month_len
    # Next line!
    next
}
{
    # remove month number into the line
    gsub(/^[0-9]+ +/, "")
    # print new line
    printf("%*.*s %s\n", tabs[k], tabs[k], "", $0)
}
```

Called as:

```bash
awk -f months.awk your_filename
```

or if you have made a `chmod 755 months.awk`:

```bash
./months.awk your_filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Try also

```
awk '
NR == 1         {split($0, Month, ";")
                 next
                }
FNR > 1         {Tmp  = $1
                 $1   = Month[$1+0]
                 if (Tmp == Last) gsub(/./, " ", $1)
                 Last = Tmp
                }
1
' - file <<< $(LC_ALL=C locale mon)
month D1 D2 D3
January 25 26 23
        13 12 11
        48 45 12
February 77 87 45
         63 99 12
```

getting the months' names from the `locale` command, translating `$1`'s number to name, and filling repeating ones with the respective count of spaces.

Comment: older versions of bash need quotes around expansions in here-strings. I don't see the point in using herestring+cmdsubst here though. Why not just `locale... | awk ... - file`? Or `awk -v months="$(locale...)"`?

Comment: Nice use of `LC_ALL=C locale mon` to get the month names!

Answer (score 1):

Script `tst.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    nums = "01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12"
    strs = "January February March April May June July August September October November December"
    n=split(nums,num); split(strs,str); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) month[num[i]] = str[i]
}

NR == 1 { print; next }
prev == $1 { $1 = sprintf("%"length(month[$1])"s"," "); print; next }
{ prev = $1; $1 = month[$1]; print }
```

Usage:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file 
month D1 D2 D3
January 25 26 23
        13 12 11
        48 45 12
February 77 87 45
         63 99 12
```

The usage of `sprintf` is anyway hacky just to get the width of the example, but this output is just for presentation, not further processing. Months are hardcoded to avoid any system call.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ awk '
    NR==1 { mth = $1 }
    NR>1  { mth = ($1==prev ? "" : strftime("%B",mktime("2020 " $1 " 15 12 0 0 0"))); prev=$1 }
    { $1 = sprintf("%-9s",mth); print }
' file
month     D1 D2 D3
January   25 26 23
          13 12 11
          48 45 12
February  77 87 45
          63 99 12
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { split("January February March April May June July August September October November December",mths) }
    NR==1 { mth = $1 }
    NR>1  { mth = ($1==prev ? "" : mths[$1+0]); prev=$1 }
    { $1 = sprintf("%-9s",mth); print }
' file
month     D1 D2 D3
January   25 26 23
          13 12 11
          48 45 12
February  77 87 45
          63 99 12
```